# How to scale background images in COMPOSITOR?

Tags: camera, compositing-nodes

The background image does not look the same as it in 3D view port. It is scaled under camera background image setting. I wonder how to scale it in compositor? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: What happens if you disable the *Scale* node?

Comment: @brockmann, if i disable scale, the bg image is right at the center. I was thinking to combine ABSOLUTE SCALE and SCENE SCALE together, but it did not work.